# mysql UNION with COUNT

Tags: mysql

I know there are many posts in similar issues to mine, but I do not seem to be able to find an applicable solution to my case, as below.

I have added null columns so that the number of columns match and I know that I need to have all columns stated in the first select. Therein lies the problem. I do not know how to include a COUNT column in the first select that would correspond to the COUNT in the second select.

Thanks for the assistance.

First select:

```
SELECT brands.brand_id, 
       brands.brand, 
       models.model_id, 
       models.model, 
       segments.segment_id, 
       segments.segment, 
       versions.version_id, 
       versions.version, 
       versions.places, 
       versions.gearbox, 
       versions.doors, 
       prices.price 
FROM   versions 
       INNER JOIN models USING (model_id) 
       INNER JOIN segments USING (segment_id) 
       INNER JOIN brands USING (brand_id) 
       INNER JOIN prices USING(version_id) 
WHERE  price BETWEEN 200001 AND 225000 
       AND brands.active = 'Y' 
       AND models.active = 'Y' 
       AND versions.active = 'Y'
```

Second select:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS SafetyItems, 
       version_id, 
       NULL     AS COL3, 
       NULL     AS ....,
       NULL     AS COL12 
FROM   versiontrim 
       INNER JOIN trims USING(trim_id) 
       INNER JOIN versions USING(version_id) 
       INNER JOIN prices USING(version_id) 
       INNER JOIN models USING (model_id) 
       INNER JOIN brands USING (brand_id) 
WHERE  trimtype IN( 'sec', 'help' ) 
       AND price BETWEEN 200001 AND 225000 
       AND brands.active = 'Y' 
       AND models.active = 'Y' 
       AND versions.active = 'Y' 
GROUP  BY version_id
```

Sample result of first select:

```
 brand_id   brand   model_id model  segment_id  version_id      price   
   58   Renault    11      Megane       4           44         209900
   58   Renault    14      Scenic       5           54         209900
   58   Renault    11      Megane       4           69         200900
   71   Toyota     29      Yaris        2          214         200900
   71   Toyota     30      Auri         4          216         207900
   52   Nissan     58      Pick-up     14          282         209000
   24   Ford       21      Focus        4          290         209000
```

Sample result of second select that I want have appended to above ( after the price column):

```
SafetyItems     version_id  
   9               44
   7               54
   9               69
  10              214
   6              216
   1              282
  10              290
```

Comment: Could you please put some sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Hi Deval, I looked at sqlfiddle.com, but I am not sure how to add a scenario as above to it. I will see what I can do.

Comment: look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0dc7/16/0 put your SQL statements

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also want to put a `NULL` column in your first `SELECT` statement that would correspond for the `COUNT` column in the second `SELECT` statement.

Just put a `NULL` column in your first `SELECT` just like in your second `SELECT` statement, that should be fine. And do not forget the `ALIAS` of the column, since `UNION` uses the column name of the first `SELECT`.

```
SELECT 
NULL AS SafetyItems,
brands.brand_id,
brands.brand,
models.model_id,
models.model,
segments.segment_id,
segments.segment,
versions.version_id,
versions.version,
versions.places,
versions.gearbox,
versions.doors,
prices.price
FROM versions
INNER JOIN models
USING (model_id)
INNER JOIN segments
USING (segment_id)
INNER JOIN brands
USING (brand_id)
INNER JOIN prices
USING(version_id)
WHERE price BETWEEN 200001 AND 225000
AND brands.active='Y'
AND models.active='Y'
AND versions.active='Y'
```

But then, you need to add another `NULL` column in the second `SELECT` to match with column count in the first `SELECT`. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Kael, but that does not work. The above will have select 2 being appended BELOW select 1 and not as columns being added to select 1 which is the desired outcome. I have added samples of each of the select for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was going about this with the wrong approach. Initially I thought I could not do select 2 with COUNT as part of select 1. It turns out it is possible and I managed to have it done after some struggling.

Thanks for the input. Please see solution below:

```
SELECT brands.brand_id, 
   brands.brand, 
   models.model_id, 
   models.model, 
   segments.segment_id, 
   segments.segment, 
   versions.version_id, 
   versions.version, 
   versions.places, 
   versions.gearbox, 
   versions.doors, 
   prices.price,
   COUNT(trimtype)
FROM   versions 
   INNER JOIN models USING (model_id) 
   INNER JOIN segments USING (segment_id) 
   INNER JOIN brands USING (brand_id) 
   INNER JOIN prices USING(version_id)
   INNER JOIN versiontrim USING(version_id)
   INNER JOIN trims USING(trim_id)
WHERE  price BETWEEN 200001 AND 210000 
   AND trimtype IN('sec', 'help')
   AND brands.active = 'Y' 
   AND models.active = 'Y' 
   AND versions.active = 'Y'
GROUP BY version_id
```